# What is the lowest value for an 8-bit binary number?

Tags: binary

What is the lowest possible value for an 8-bit signed magnitude binary number?
Is it 11111111 or 00000001?

Comment: @hatchet That's not a duplicate I asked in signed magnitude not in two's complement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bit, 1, is the negative sign. To get the biggest smallest number (:P) you try to get the largest binary number you can, without the bit describes the negativity, so it's 11111111, and the decimal value is -127

Comment: You mean -127 (the value represented) or 255 (the unsigned byte value that represents it)? One bit for the sign leaves 7 for magnitude.

Comment: Actually, i thought the same, but i had a digital system exam and i understood it better: if u have a number with 8 numbers, the biggest possible representation is 511 (cause if u add a 1 bit it'll be 512 and 100000000), so if we put aside the bit for magnitude we are left with 7 bits, and with these 7 bits we can represent 255. If my explanation wasnt clear enough, pls tell me

Comment: The explanation was clear enough, but the math is wrong. A 7-bit number can represent unsigned values from 0 to 127. (2^7 = 128 possible values.) And 100000000 is 256, not 512.

Comment: Well, you are right man! i missed a bit in my calculations, but you get the general idea, with 8 bits and a magnitude bit we have 7 bits, and as you said we can get -127! sorry for misleading a bit there

Comment: Makes more sense now :)